# la direccion generada de bitcoin no corresponde

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando convertir las 12 palabras en direcciones BTC, pero no coinciden con las que me muestran Safepal, Coinomi y Trust Wallet.
he intentado con varias librerias o de manera manual

Logré convertir con éxito a SegWit, pero P2PKH y P2SH aún no coinciden.

las palabras(son de prueba) son:

```
false deal abstract advance buffalo clock auto banana offer arena wage stumble
```

lo que uso para convertir esas dos maneras que no logro es la siguiente:

```
################# P2PKH ##############

seed = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', mnemonic.encode('utf-8'), b'mnemonic', 2048)
private_key = seed[:32]
public_key = hashlib.sha256(private_key).digest()
ripemd160 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
ripemd160.update(public_key)
hash160 = ripemd160.digest()
version = b"\x00" # versión para direcciones P2PKH en red principal de Bitcoin
address_bytes = version + hash160
checksum = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(address_bytes).digest()).digest()[:4]
addressP2PKH = base58.b58encode(address_bytes + checksum).decode('utf-8')

################ P2SH ##############

seed = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', mnemonic.encode('utf-8'), b'mnemonic', 2048)
private_key = seed[:32]
sk = SigningKey.from_string(private_key, curve=SECP256k1)
vk = sk.get_verifying_key()
public_key_bytes = vk.to_string()
hashed_public_key = hashlib.sha256(public_key_bytes).digest()
ripe_hash = hashlib.new('ripemd160', hashed_public_key).digest()
prefix = b'\x05'
prefixed_ripe_hash = prefix + ripe_hash
address_bytes = hashlib.sha256(prefixed_ripe_hash).digest()
address_bytes = hashlib.sha256(address_bytes).digest()
checksum = address_bytes[:4]
raw_address = prefixed_ripe_hash + checksum
addressP2SH = base58.b58encode(raw_address).decode()

print(['segwitAddress', 'addressP2PKH', 'addressP2SH'])
```

la salida es:

```
['bc1qfev3mh2mz3cuvsfn3wt6rwv78qjlkcy7dj27dk', '14ZowctPoxYtaUa55XKpUq8h2VWzPvLQ84', '37qZKk7ZpFFX63fR4HLPRaU5jtdhckmcnP']
```

cuando deberia ser:

```
['bc1qfev3mh2mz3cuvsfn3wt6rwv78qjlkcy7dj27dk', '1D9P3s1Daa3dmLq88QAky3uv4vjT6WZRCV', '3HojBjoLmEHjrHfiiUKAL1NCVXEcmAf7iY']
```